# Add class to child elements and start over for next container with the same parent class

Tags: java, jquery

I want to assign classes to the elements inside each container.

I tried this script which gves the child elements its classes but it keeps going for each container, one, two, three, four and then for next container five, six, seven and eight.

```
$('.container span').each(function(i){
$(this).addClass('class'+i);
})
```

How do I do this and have the added classes starting over for the next parent container?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span></span> - assign class one
    <span></span> - assign class two
    <span></span> - assign class three
    <span></span> - assign class four
</div>

<div class="container">
    <span></span> - assign class one
    <span></span> - assign class two
    <span></span> - assign class three
    <span></span> - assign class four
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('.container').each(function () {
    $(this).find('span').each(function (i) {
        $(this).addClass('class' + i);
    });
});
```

Iterate through every element with class `.container` and then find `span` inside it and add class..